# Include variables from one template file into another template in Django

Tags: django

I have a template file temp1.html having code like this ---

```
{% load customtags %}  
{% get_val 'VAR1' as var1 %}  {% get_val 'VAR1' as var2 %}
```

In second template file temp2.html i want to use these variables `var1`, `var2` and `var3`. 
I am going to use these variables in multiple template files. So want to reuse the code every where.
I am including the temp1.html into temp2.html but these variables are not accessible into the temp2.html

```
{% include 'temp1.html' %}
```

So how to use these variables in another template files ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's possible to share values from the custom tags between various templates, so sorry if this doesn't answer exactlly to your specifications.

But when I needed to pass various variables to differents template I used a custom context_processor:
You could define your contextual variable in a file like 'my_app.context_processors.py'

```
from django.conf import settings
from my_app.models import Authorization


def custom_contexts(request):
    try:
        user_level_projects = Authorization.get_user_level_projects(request.user)
    except Exception:
        user_level_projects = {}

    # you can put here dynamics or constants data that will be accessible via the 
    # standard template syntaxes: ex -> {{ FILE_MAX_SIZE }}    
    return {
        'APPLICATION_NAME': settings.APPLICATION_NAME,
        'LOGO_PATH': settings.LOGO_PATH,
        'APPLICATION_ABSTRACT': settings.APPLICATION_ABSTRACT,
        'IMAGE_FORMAT': settings.IMAGE_FORMAT,
        'FILE_MAX_SIZE': settings.FILE_MAX_SIZE,
        'USER_LEVEL_PROJECTS': user_level_projects
   }
```

then you have to add this new context_processor in your 'settings.py'

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'my_app.context_processors.custom_contexts',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

NB: In this example 'USER_LEVEL_PROJECTS' is actually a dictionary, but it could be anything else.
I cannot find where in the doc I found this, but I'm sure you will find more infos.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Niark !  This is meeting my need.  I was looking for the same thing but trying to do in another way .

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.